# Field 'tile' could not be resolved with typedef struct

Tags: c++, c, sdl, game-engine

Hey guys this shouldn't be that hard, but why does

```
            fscanf(fp, "%d", Map.tile[x][y]);
```

The tile part says Field 'tile' could not be resolved
Sorry for having beginner problems, but Im guessing it should be a problem with char to int conversions.
How would I fix this?
Thanks,
waco001

```
void MapManager::loadMap(char *name){
    int x, y;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(name, "rb");
    const int MAX_MAP_Y = 32;
    const int MAX_MAP_X = 32;
    typedef struct Map
    {
        int tile[MAX_MAP_Y][MAX_MAP_X];
        char xs;
    } Map;
    /* If we can't open the map then exit */

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open map %s\n", name);

        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the data from the file into the map */

    for (y=0;y<MAX_MAP_Y;y++)
    {
        for (x=0;x<MAX_MAP_X;x++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", Map.tile[x][y]);
        }
    }

    /* Close the file afterwards */

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` is a type but you need an object. You could, e.g., use

```
Map map;
// ...
if (fscanf(fp, "%d", map.tile[x][y]) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to read map.tile[%d][%d]\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Wow such a stupid mistake from me not knowing my basics... Thanks